# How to synthesize a static virtual/abstract member?

Tags: c#, oop

I know that syntactically and conceptually the concepts of "virtual" and "static" members are diametrically opposed, but I'm trying to push the envelope a bit and see if there's a way to achieve the following:

Let's say I have an abstract class `Animal`, which has a property `NumberOfLegs`.  My `Cat` class should have `NumberOfLegs` defined as 4, while `Spider` should have 8 legs.  I would want to have code like this (obviously the code below will not compile):

```
public abstract class Animal {
  public static abstract int NumberOfLegs { get; }

  public void Walk() {
    // do something based on NumberOfLegs
  }
}

public class Cat : Animal {
  public static override int NumberOfLegs { get { return 4; } }
}

public class Spider : Animal {
  public static override int NumberOfLegs { get { return 8; } }
}
```

I want it to be static, because it's not dependent on instance; it's dependent only on the subclass type.

How would you do this?

Comment: Does the member really need to be static? The value under the member can be static regardless.

Comment: @Josh is right -- it doesn't matter if it doesn't vary by instance -- just make it an instance method.

Comment: @JoshC. - in this example, there's no real loss in having an instance member.  The real life example I'm working on, though, is where the property is a set of field mappings... something quite a lot more complex than a simple constant, which I don't want to have to rerun every time I have a new instance of the subclass.

Comment: @Shaul, you can *still* store that static data in a static field and pay the penalty for initializing it just once.   And return that in your instance method.

Comment: @KirkWoll - true.  That would be my fallback position.  But it's not as *neat* as I would want it to be... :-)

Comment: Perhaps, but I suspect the problem is that you are using the concept of `static` as a means of organizing your code (and your thoughts), rather than as a means to surface specific behavior.  If you want something to vary by ancestry, that is polymorphism, and static methods do not make sense in such a scenario.

Comment: @KirkWoll - I'm not locked in to the keyword `static`.  I just want to find a way to code this particular behavior in a way that doesn't require a call to an instance method in order to get a value that is shared across the entire definition of the descendant class.

Comment: What about the prototype design pattern? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern

Comment: @JoshC. - not sure how prototype pattern answers the question?

Comment: @Shaul "*I just want to find a way to code this particular behaviour in a way that doesn't require a call to an instance method*" - In a nut shell, you can't simply because `static` methods cannot be declared as `virtual`. An alternative solution would be to have an `AnimalLegFactory` which given a specific type returns you the correct number of legs which you could invoke via your `static` property. However, that means your taking the definition out of the class, which you may not like, but you have to make a compromise somewhere for this to work.

Comment: @Shaul Perhaps it's not directly the prototype pattern, but the idea is this: Have some Creator object which has knowledge of types statically or single-ly. Your creator object can be called for questions on the types without instantiating them. Then, when your ready, ask your Creator to create the type.

Comment: @Shaul simply put, I'm not exactly sure why the static information needs to be embedded in the type. You could build static information that is related to a type strongly that is not embedded in the type. Then, a factory could inject the right stuff on creation.

Comment: How do you plan to invoke the static method? Via an object or by directly calling the class method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best compromise for you is to create a constant in each class for the number of legs. A constant is basically a static member which is readonly, which for this example makes sense, otherwise make it static.

Next, I would define an abstract Property for the Animal class and override it each subclass. This would allow inheritance and polymorphism to work, but each instance of the class would still reference the same value.

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract int NumberOfLegs { get; }

    public void Walk()
    {
        // do something based on NumberOfLegs
    }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    private const int NumLegs = 4;

    public override int NumberOfLegs { get { return NumLegs; } }
}

public class Spider : Animal
{
    private const int NumLegs = 8;

    public override int NumberOfLegs { get { return NumLegs; } }
}
```

As far as not being to override static methods, I know it isn't what you want to hear but that's not possible. First of all, you use static members like Animal.Legs or Cat.Legs by specifying the class and not from an instance of the object. Therefore, if you define it as static, you won't even have access on it from an instance of the class, and there is no idea of polymorphism either (i.e. a function accepting a generic "Animal" cannot get how many legs it has and have it call the correct Property). If you are interested in how this works I suggest you read about [Virtual Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)

Comment: Not the answer I'm looking for, but since it's apparent that what I want can't be done, I'll give you answer credit anyway.  :-)